# Can't start Nginx, Brotli configuration error

Tags: nginx, debian

I have a nginx server setup as a reverse proxy for apache2 on a Debian 9 OS. Apache2 is running on a different port than 80. I was trying to renew my site's certificate using certbot, and I ran this command somewhere during the process:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-certbot-nginx
```

I think that this installed a fresh copy of nginx server on my machine(correct me if I am wrong please) and since then nginx hasn't been able to start. Following are the results from the test commands:

#### `nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so" failed (/usr/share/nginx/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so: cann
ot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/brotli.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

#### `nginx -V`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-8G38mz/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time 
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --er
ror-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/va
r/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-tem
p-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_r
equest_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-
http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic 
--with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8G38mz/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-m
odule=/build/nginx-8G38mz/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8G38mz/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynami
c-module=/build/nginx-8G38mz/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8G38mz/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitution
s_filter_module
```

#### `sudo systemctl status nginx`:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-04-11 01:20:12 CEST; 14min ago
     Docs: man:nginnginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so" failed (/usr/share/nginx/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so: cann
ot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/brotli.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failedx(8)
  Process: 22395 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 11 01:20:12 cp-com-vm systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 11 01:20:12 cp-com-vm nginx[22395]: nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so" failed (/usr/share/nginx/nginx/module
Apr 11 01:20:12 cp-com-vm nginx[22395]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Apr 11 01:20:12 cp-com-vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 11 01:20:12 cp-com-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Apr 11 01:20:12 cp-com-vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 11 01:20:12 cp-com-vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

#### `nginx.conf`:

```
   #user  nginx;
 worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

 #pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

 include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

 http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;
#tcp_nodelay        on;

#gzip  on;
#gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

server_tokens off;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
client_max_body_size 512M;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

#### `brotli.conf`:

```
load_module nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
load_module nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;
```

I have tried a lot of answers from different sites on how to get my server back up to no avail, can someone please pinpoint to the exact problem? FYI-I was able to renew the certificate afterwards, so now I am only left with this problem. TIA

Comment: Are you confident that you have Brotli? Because Brotli is not a standard included module, try to comment it out or remove the config.

Comment: @djdomi I don't understand where am I supposed to comment it out, in the brotli.conf file or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what I tried, I wasn't able to fix my then current installation of nginx. My nginx.conf always failed even though I installed brotli separately and tried commenting it in the configuration.

I had to purge the instance of nginx and reinstall it to get it up and running again:

```
apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Basically you had just to remove the brotli.conf out of the modules 

Comment: @djdomi I tried that. Didn't work, i even tried turning Brotli off in the conf.

Comment: this fact was not told at all in the current progress, remember that you need to accept your own answer

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you for the reminder.